# Prestashop - List ordering

Tags: php, list, prestashop, backend, prestashop-1.6

I am creating a new Prestashop (>= v. 1.6) module. I have created a `getContent()` method as described in their documentation. How can I create a list from which a user can sort items. So, they can move around the items from the list and the ordering will be saved into the database?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a database table for that ObjectModel, creat a class for that model that extends ObjectModel, and a controller that extends ModuleAdminController.

Also, when a module is installed a new tab must be added, so the page will appear at the BackOffice menu. For reference take a look how "Features" are implemented.